# Получению сырца-xml по xsd

Tags: xml, java

Доброго всем дня)

На форуме уже поднимался вопрос по получению сырца-xml по xsd. Воспользовался рекомендациями, но у меня возникли проблемы. С командной строки действительно работает, но затащил к себе в код - получаю исключение. Начал отлаживаться - похоже не работает правильно парсер - причем не бросает исключения, а выдает XmlObject - с неопределенным типом. Естественно compilerXSD - сразу бросает исключение. Пишу plug-in под eclipce, отлаживаюсь с eclipce application.

Помогите разобраться)))

---

xsd2inst apache xmlbeans 2.5.0

Comment: Добавлю еще - что это происходит в обработчике события от кнопки. Попробовал код перенести в конструктор диалога - все работает. Я еще больше озадачен. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Уточню - приложение SWT JFace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Продвигаюсь дальше - похоже дело не в обработчике. Я динамически подгружаю классы и баг начинает проявляться после таких кодов

```
loader=new URLClassLoader(urls);
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(loader);
```

- когда я устанавливаю в контекст свой класс-лоадер. Мож я чего не так делаю? Мож после нужно вычищать свой лоадер из контекста?
Посоветуйте неопытному)))

**Добавлено**.

Запоминаю через `getContextClassLoader` - текущий лоадер и восстанавливаю его после завершения работы со своим. Наверное это нормальная культура программирования. Остаюсь в недоумении - почему парсер просто молчал - если внутрях не отработал егошный лоадер).  Потом `setContextClassLoader` - логично не void-овскую иметь - ну возвращали бы туда текущий лоадер))) Это сразу наводило бы на мысль))) Удачи всем)))